# how to properly make a POST request using Java Apache HttpClient?

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I am trying to use a web API in a Java program using Apache HttpClient5.

Using a simple request with `curl`:

```
curl -X POST -H "x-api-user: d904bd62-da08-416b-a816-ba797c9ee265" -H "x-api-key: xxxxxxxxxxx" https://habitica.com/api/v3/user/class/cast/valorousPresence
```

I get the expected response and effect.

Using my Java code:

```java
URI uri = new URIBuilder()
              .setScheme("https")
              .setHost("habitica.com")
              .setPath("/api/v3/user/class/cast/valorousPresence")
              .build();
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
httpPost.addHeader(new BasicHeader("x-api-user",getApiUser()));
httpPost.addHeader(new BasicHeader("x-api-key", getApiKey()));
CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
logger.info(httpResponse.toString());
return httpResponse.getCode();
```

The output I get when running the Java call is

```
411 Length Required HTTP/1.0
```

I'm sure I'm not constructing the POST call correctly, how should it be done? I've tried specifying Content-Type and that has no effect. Trying to set Content-Length in the code causes compilation errors (as I understand it, this is handled behind the scenes by HttpClient5).
All my GET requests using HttpClient5 work fine.

Comment: It's not about the client. The server, which receives the HTTP message doesn't accept it without the `Content-Length` header. See more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/411).

Comment: A `POST` always has a payload (content). A `POST` without content is unusual, so are you sure you didn't forget something? You need to call `setEntity()` to set the payload, even if it is empty, because it is the entity that sets the Content-Length. E.g. you could call `httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(""))`, which sets `Content-Type: text/plain` and `Content-Length: 0`

Comment: @Andreas Thank you, this worked. If you'd like to add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `POST` always has a payload (content). A `POST` without content is unusual, so are you sure you didn't forget something?

You need to call `setEntity()` to set the payload, even if it is empty, because it is the entity that sets the `Content-Length` header.

E.g. you could call `httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(""))`, which sets `Content-Type: text/plain` and `Content-Length: 0`.